# Having problems determining xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This one has me stumped. Usually I will use the Firebug feature to obtain the xpath for me but this time it doesn't seem to be working.

We have a US and UK version of our website. Firebug's xpath works on the US version but not on the UK version. If I grab the xpath using Firebug it's the exact same xpath for both sites but it works on the US version of the site and fails on the UK version of the site.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <a class="ng-scope" ng-click="flightSearch.sort.$select(featuredItinerary.sortOrder)" tooltip="">
    <h3 class="ng-binding">Fastest</h3>
       <div class="row sort-block-row">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="ng-binding">$283</h2>
       </div>
```

I want to capture the value of the $283. This value will change constantly.

Here is what Firebug is telling me the xpath value is:

```
 //html/body/div[2]/main/div/ui-view/ui-view/section/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a/div/div[1]/h2
```

Anyone have a better xpath value I can try and hope it works for both sites?

Comment: This is indeed a horrible xpath which seems to me petty vulnerable. If you can provide the HTML DOM I can help you to derive a better xpath.

Comment: If you can, post a link the US and UK versions of the site and we can help. Otherwise, please post the HTML of the desired element along with some of the relevant, surrounding HTML.

Comment: I can't post the URL's but I'll update the original post with the relevant and surrounding HTML.

Comment: Assuming you are always going to be looking for the "fastest" price, I believe it could be shortened to:

//h3[contains(.,'Fastest')]/div[2]/h2

Comment: Difficult to tell x-path from this snippet of html. Please post the dom as well or tell us the link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Following **xpath** should be able to help fetching the required value:

```
//a/h3[text()='Fastest']/descendant::h2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these below `xpath`

Assuming You are going to access the `Fastest` price.

**Explanation:** Start your xpath with `<h3>` tag using `text` method to match text as `Fastest`. Then move ahead with `<h2>` tag using `following` keyword. Because your `<h2>` tag is consider price.

```
//h3[contains(text(), 'Fastest')]/following::h2
```

> OR

**Explanation:** Use `class` attribute of `<div>` tag. Then move ahead with `<h2>` tag. Because your  tag is consider price.

```
//div[@class='col-xs-12']/h2
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.